# escaping characters in c++ and for loops

Tags: c++, loops

Hi i have the following code and i will like to go through the string list with a for loop to create all possible variations , I have a problem understanding how to print the string including all the "" and , 
 something like this :

```
 "","""polo-M-GRE""","polo-M-GRE","Products","Unit",0,"","","","Size","Medium",0,0.0,0.0,0.0,"","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","Colour","TTR",0,0.0,0.0,0.0,"","","","","",""
```

any help will be welcome thanks.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    string size_attr[] = {"Extra Small","Small","Medium","Large","Extra Large"};
    string size_abv[]={"XS","S","M","L","XL"};
    string color_attr[]={"Red","Green","Blue","Black","White"};
    string color_abv[]={"RED","GRE","BLU","BLA","WHI"};
    for (int i = 0; i <= (sizeof (size_attr) / sizeof (*size_attr)); i++) {
        for (int y = 0; y <= 4; y++) {
            cout << "\"\""",""""polo-M-RED""","polo-M-RED","Products","Unit",0,"","","","Size","Medium",0,0.0,0.0,0.0,"","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","Colour","Red",0,0.0,0.0,0.0,"","","","","",""<< endl;
        }
    }
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking for. You're not using your array variables at all, and it's not clear what your output needs to look like. Are you trying to write a csv file? `<=` is also being used incorrectly in at least the outside loop. It's not clear what the inside loop is meant to do.

Comment: The comma operator doesn't do what you think it does here.

Comment: You need either, to create an inner loop over each array, or to create a generic recursion to iterate all possible cases.

Comment: Are you asking how to escape the quotation marks?

Answer (score 0):

I thought that you want to output `size_attr[]` and `color_attr[]`.
Look for last `cout<<`, that is escape character.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    string size_attr[] = {"Extra Small","Small","Medium","Large","Extra Large"};
    string size_abv[]={"XS","S","M","L","XL"};
    string color_attr[]={"Red","Green","Blue","Black","White"};
    string color_abv[]={"RED","GRE","BLU","BLA","WHI"};

    //"","""polo-M-GRE""","polo-M-GRE","Products","Unit",0,"","","","Size","Medium",0,0.0,0.0,0.0,"","","","","","" "","","","","","","","","","Colour","TTR",0,0.0,0.0,0.0,"","","","","",""
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof (size_attr) / sizeof (*size_attr)); i++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <= 4; y++)
        {
//          cout <<"\"\",\"\"\"polo-M-RED\"\"\",\"polo-M-RED\",\"Products\",\"Unit\",0,\"\",\"\",\"\",\"Size\",\"Medium\",0,0.0,0.0,0.0,\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\" \"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"Colour\",\"Red\",0,0.0,0.0,0.0,\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\""<< endl;
            cout <<"\"\",\"\"\"polo-M-RED\"\"\",\"polo-M-RED\",\"Products\",\"Unit\",0,\"\",\"\",\"\","<<size_attr[i]<<",\"Medium\",0,0.0,0.0,0.0,\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\" \"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"Colour\",\""<<color_attr[y]<<"\",0,0.0,0.0,0.0,\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\""<<endl;
        }
    }

    //Output escape characters
    cout<<" \" ' < > , . ~ ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + - = [ ] { } : ; ? / | \\"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Result :

[Printed Screen Outputs - Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwfV2.png)